# social studio case creation in SFDC

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect, social-studio

i have created a macros which i have linked it with my salesforce org. I tried applying the marcos to the post(facebook & twitter). I get a message saying macros applied with the note of salesforce org id but when i check SFDC for the case, i dont find any cases in SFDC. Is there any other procedure that i need to follow to send the case to SFDC? It was working couple of months back but when i test it now its not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you push a post in from an existing author and that author has an existing open case (or a case that has been closed for less time than your defined reopen period), the Social Posts will thread into the existing case. A new case will only be created if there is no existing open case for that author or if there are no cases that have been closed in the last reopen days.